# Creating a native installer from Griffon application

Tags: groovy, griffon

Is there any way to create a native (.rpm, .deb) installer with all required depedencies listed (e.g. some other packages needed) for lets say Ubuntu distro?

Comment: That was silly question, but since I've looked at griffon few days ago for the first time.... answer is here: http://griffon.codehaus.org/Installer+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting follow up comment as answer:

The [Installer plugin](http://griffon.codehaus.org/Installer+Plugin) provides the desired behavior.